# typing to use GmapsFX in javaFXML file

Tags: java, google-maps, javafx, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to do Google maps integration with JavaFXML files. I have imported the GMapsFX gluon jar file but there still seems to be a problem.

Here is the FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" 
minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="602.0" prefWidth="540.0" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <GoogleMapView layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="602.0" prefWidth="540.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

My controller class doesn't have any notable code in it so it's not worth showing, but the error is found at the first gmapsfx import and on the googlemaps view pane.

Here is the error message after running:

```
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2848)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2692)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2661)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at SignInAfterPage.SignInAfterPageController.createScene2(SignInAfterPageController.java:60)
at SignInAfterPage.SignInAfterPageController.openMapPage(SignInAfterPageController.java:41)
... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2916)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2905)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2846)
... 70 more
```

Comment: https://rterp.wordpress.com/2016/08/22/mapping-directions-with-javafx-using-the-gmapsfx-directions-api/

Comment: what is that? ??

Comment: no, I couldn't find any downloadable libraries. How do i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project dont work because you haven't the library.

> two solutions :

- Dowwnload the library and add manualy a dpendency to it ([here](https://github.com/rterp/GMapsFX/releases))
- Use a build tool like `Maven` or `Gradle` to create this dependency

the first is the easier to begin and the second in the most use in corporation

Comment: error lines have gone but now getting logger factory error

Comment: could you ckeck out my most recent post (HIDE ALERT)